# How to custom transition from other app to my app

Tags: ios

My app share a interesting url to twitter or wechat,and return to my app.

Before my app call the `applicationWillEnterForeground`,the system will show a transition from twitter or wechat to my app.

Default,the transition show the LaunchScreen.storyboard snapshot.

How to custom the transition?Can I change the transition snapshot to my favorite image?